# VBA read XML only works for local XML files

Tags: xml, vba

I was running the following code

```
    Sub test()
        'XML = "C:\R_20130408_1.xml" 'This is local, and works fine
        XML = "http://www.treasurydirect.gov/xml/R_20130408_1.xml" 'This get nothing for "point"
        Dim objXML As DOMDocument
        Dim point As IXMLDOMNode
        Set objXML = New DOMDocument
        With objXML
            .Load XML
            Set point = .SelectSingleNode("//AuctionAnnouncement/CUSIP")
            Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2) = point.Text
        End With

    End Sub
```

As you can see, if I download this XML from the web, I can get it working, otherwise, objXML will still load, but point will be nothing.

Would anybody offer some thoughts on this?

Many thanks!
Ji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible the XML headers/layout are different between the local XML file, and the remote file?  I was able to get the HTTP version working, by changing the XPath to this string: `"*/AuctionAnnouncement/CUSIP"`

Comment: Thank you! However I think there is some problem on my PC...When I run this, the bug comes out:"The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available". However, when I click Debug, and F8 forward, the code will run correctly. Somehow, "point" is not activated in the first time, and I need to manually F8 it to work...

Comment: But for now, I circumvent this problem by downloading it to local drive by URLDownloadtoFile

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your issue.  Try setting the 'Async' property to false for your DOMDocument:  'objXML.async = false' before your .Load.  See if that helps